# Matlab fmincon optimization result changes absed on display style

Tags: matlab, optimization

As part of a research project, I am optimizing over a user-defined function that I know (numerically and analytically) is well behaved (quasi-concave) and I am trying to use fmincon to find certain optima.

If I specify ('Display','off') as an option, fmincon runs, exits normally and gives me the WRONG, solution. If I specify ('Display', 'on') as an option, fmincon throws an exception and stops. Using the same parameters and the same functions, one can manually check that the optimal solutions is ~2.4.

```
clear all
%Model Parameters
global r e nDay nNight muH muL sigH sigL DH DL pH pL g cS cG bH BH IntBH bL BL IntBL QLim batSeq genSeq 
r = 0.3;
nDay = 14;
nNight = 24- nDay;
muH = nDay * r;
muL = nNight * r;
sigH = sqrt(nDay * r * (1-r));
sigL = sqrt(nNight * r * (1-r));
QLim = fix(((DH+DL)/r - DH)/1000)*1000;
g = 50;
cG = 11.1;
pH = 37;
pL = 23;
DH = 65000;
DL = 35000;
genSeq = 80000 
e = 0.9; %0.9 for battery %0.45 for Kraftblock
cS = 30; %60 for Battery %9 for Kraftblock

%Create integrals of specific normal cdfs (helper functions)
bH = @(x) exp(-((x-muH).^2)/(2*sigH.^2)) / (sigH*sqrt(2*pi));
BH = @(y) integral(@(x) bH(x), 0, y);
IntBH = @(z) integral(@(y) BH(y), 0, z, 'ArrayValued',true);
bL = @(x) exp(-((x-muL).^2)/(2*sigL.^2)) / (sigL*sqrt(2*pi));
BL = @(y) integral(@(x) bL(x), 0, y);
IntBL = @(z) integral(@(y) BL(y), 0, z, 'ArrayValued',true);
```

Optimization starts here (essentially square the derivative and find the minimum (i.e.0) of that)

```
counter = 0;
fval = [];
exitflag = [];
output = [];
for i = genSeq
    counter = counter + 1;
    fixed_Q = i
    jt3PartialKFixQ = @(K) jt3PartialK(fixed_Q, K)^2;
    try
        options = optimoptions('fmincon','Display','off');
        [x,fval,exitflag,output] = fmincon(jt3PartialKFixQ, 0, [], [], [], [] ,0, 14, [], options)
        jt3FixQRes(counter,:) = [x, i];
        disp(x)
    catch
        disp([i,"None Found"])
    end
end

%The function to be optimized
function profit = jt3PartialK(Q,K)
global r e nDay nNight muH muL sighH sigL DH DL pH pL g cS cG bH BH IntBH bL BL IntBL QLim
    V = min((Q-DL)/(Q-DH),100);
    profit = g*e*(1-BH(K*V)) - ...
        (g*e*sqrt(r))/((DL+DH)/r - DH) * (Q-DH)* (1-BH(K*V)) + ...
        g*e*(1-BL(K)) -...
        (g*e*sqrt(r))/((DL+DH)/r - DH) * (Q-DH)* (1-BL(K)) - ...
        cS;
end
```

Why does the display function have any bearing on the result of the optimization? Any help to figure out how to get this to solve properly (for most parameter combinations it just runs and optimizes as expected) would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting an error because `on` is not a valid input for the option `Display`. For [all valid options](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html#busog7r-options) the optimized value that I find is 1.4190, which seems to be the correct value.
[image]

Comment: You are right - can't believe that this is MATLAB's default behavior though. Thank you for pointing it out.